# Can I get a reference to the object binded in the XAML from my UserControl class?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have a XAML paired with a cs class that inherits from UserControl class. I would like to access in this class to the object being binded (binding source) in the XAML, and make some changes in the UI depending on some properties of the object when an event is triggered. Is there a way to manage this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `DataContext`.  From your `UserControl`'s cs class:

```
var myObject = (MyType)this.DataContext;
myObject.PropertyChanged += myHandler;
```

Note that the `DataContext` won't be set when you're in the constructor.  You should be able to get it in the `Loaded` event or later.